# bootstrap: stretch the content div in the center

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, nav

I'd like to fill the content div to the space in the middle of header and footer.

Currently header and footer are styled using `bootstrap:

header:

```
<nav id="header" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

footer:

```
<nav id="footer" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    test footer  
  </div>
</nav>
```

content:

```
<div id="content" class="panel panel-default">
  ...
</div>
```

css code for the content div is

```
.content{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 50px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

It works well if the header/footer heights are fixed at `50px`. Any idea to do once the header/footer heights are changing due to different screen sizes.

[image]

Comment: can you share the code for your navbars?

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries and define the div height for every screen size your header/footer has a different height in.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Maybe you could share a jsfiddle with your code?

Answer (score 0):

If your header and footer remains at 50px height in all devices you could do something like below:

```
.content{
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: sorry. header/footer heights are changed as well

Comment: Then you should override the height attribute of the content div in media queries where the header and footer height changes. Something like: height: calc(100% - (headerHeight + footerHeight));